# Performance of property-access

Tags: c#, properties

Within my company we got a briefing for performance-issues. One of the points mentioned there was the access of properties because most of them are retrieved from a database. Thus querying the object itself may result in expensive calls to underlying database.

Now I wonder if there is any difference between the following two statements (considering performace at least)

```
MyPropertyValue value = myObject.SomeProperty ?? ...;
```

And

```
MyPropertyValue value = (myObject.SomeProperty != null) ? 
    myObject.SomeProperty : 
    ...
```

I suppose the former is a kind of shortcut for the latter and thus also results in two queries on the property, is this true?

Thanks for ya

Comment: that would depend if the properties support lazy loading, no?

Comment: First expression will evaluate `SomeProperty` only once whereas latter will evaluate twice. So answer depends on how expensive the property is.

Comment: Ah, I see... so my assumption was incorrect. Better for me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example only access the `get` of the property once, and the second accesses it twice.

now, if the `get` does a DB call EVERY time, then the first is definitely better.

Tested in LinqPad

Answer (score 1):

First expression will evaluate `SomeProperty` only once whereas latter will evaluate twice.

So answer depends on how expensive the property is. Generally speaking properties should be cheap. If you have a property which takes a while to return you should consider refactoring it to a method instead.

<sub>If you have a more specific question, you may get a specific answer.</sub>

Comment: Well, the question is not on performance of the property itself, but only to which of these two opportunities does less. I got my answer, thanks